# MongoDB mongoimport error - how to handle

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

I'm importing json files to create and update a mongodb database. Now I iterate the filesystem and run a `mongoimport` on each json file, which consists of multiple json documents separated by newline (which is what mongoimport expects), not a jsonArray.

I periodically get this output, for example:

```
2016-08-27T21:21:37.153+0000    Failed: error processing document #422: invalid character '3' in string escape code
2016-08-27T21:21:37.153+0000    imported 420 documents
```

Is there a way to keep track of
(1) how many documents should have been loaded vs how many were actually loaded and (2) keep track or store the documents that the upload failed for so they can be processed later?

EDIT: There appears to be no way to error handle in `mongoimport`. It either works, or it stops working once it runs into trouble. The answer here was to use UNIX tools (`sed`, `grep`, ...) to fix the data before putting it in the database. You have to be completely sure of the data before you run `mongoimport`.

Comment: It's recommended to check correctness of JSON import document before running `mongoimport`. Also check `--stopOnError` flag. it will force `mongoimport` to stop processing more documents when encountered a problem.